# Add to Chrome app titlebar

Tags: google-chrome-app, title, titlebar

I would like to add a button in the titlebar of a Chrome app. Most of my research has lead me to believe that the only way to do this is by disabling the default titlebar and making my own. Is there a way to simply add a button to the existing titlebar? If not, is there a resource that has detailed tutorials or examples of removing the default titlebar and making a custom titlebar?

Comment: Quick note, "is there a resource that has detailed tutorials or examples" is considered an [off-topic question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there isn't a way to add buttons to "default" titlebars. That wouldn't be portable anyway.

What you can do is create a frameless app window:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    'outerBounds': {
      'width': 400,
      'height': 500
    },
    'frame': 'none' // It will be a rectangle filled with your HTML
  });
});
```

There is a [sample app](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/frameless-window) that implements this and also a [draggable](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#draggable) title bar.

You can use any kind of framework to make an area that looks like a title bar on your page's top, like Bootstrap's [navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/), and implement actions like close/maximize/minimize using [`chrome.app.window` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window) - get a reference to the current `AppWindow` and use its [methods](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-AppWindow).

Comment: Thank you! I now have a customized titlebar.